# CRUD api - connecting frontend and backend

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, api, crud

I want to know basic of creating an api key to connecting frontend and backend via an API with basic CRUD function...

So I have a database:

```
CREATE TABLE STATION 
(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
CITY CHAR(20), 
STATE CHAR(2), 
LAT_N REAL, 
LONG_W REAL);

populate the table STATION with a few rows:

INSERT INTO STATION VALUES (13, 'Phoenix', 'AZ', 33, 112); 
INSERT INTO STATION VALUES (44, 'Denver', 'CO', 40, 105); 
INSERT INTO STATION VALUES (66, 'Caribou', 'ME', 47, 68);
```

and TABLE in HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/59nHw/

Now I want to know how to build an API to do basic CRUD functions into HTML code and populate - update mysql database?

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/creating-an-api-centric-web-application/

Answer (score 6):

I think you can check out [Configure.IT](http://www.configure.it)'s Backend Panel & API Builder tool.

By which you can create a dynamic CRUD RestAPI as well as Admin Modules without any code.

You can review all the diff features as below.

http://www.configure.it/features/mobile-app-data-panel/

I hope this will help you out.